# Asp.Net MVC model validation special characters issue

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

I am trying to validate special characters with the below regular expression. It is blocking special characters properly, but it is also blocking numbers. Is there any way for it not to throw error on entering numbers?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Project Title")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage = "special characters are       not allowed.")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding 0-9 should do the trick.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", 
    ErrorMessage = "special characters are       not  allowed.")]
```